# Google Sheets API Client - How to get single sheet data

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get all data from single sheet of spreadsheet. If I want to get data from first sheet of spreadsheet it's quite simple.

```
$sheetsService->spreadsheets_values->get($sheetId, $range);
```

where `$sheetService` is instance of `Google_Service_Sheets`

Is there any way to specify `index` or `name` of sheet I want to get data from?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the only available methods for reading values in Sheets API is [Reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading) using the A1 Notation which I think you are currently using. Try filing a feature [request here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry).